# Jenkins remote build issue - email related

Tags: git, jenkins

I am running Jenkins 1.424.6 as this is the only version I can use in Ubunutu 12.04 without compiling from source; I know it's an older version.

I've got a job attempting to build when there are commits to the test branch of a GIT project, however they fail with this output:

```
Started by remote host 127.0.0.1
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@repo:project.git
Checking out Revision 745755b40716cc220f9635db7b555af65dd283b2 (origin/test)
FATAL: hudson.tasks.Mailer$UserProperty.hasExplicitlyConfiguredAddress()Z
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:         
hudson.tasks.Mailer$UserProperty.hasExplicitlyConfiguredAddress()Z
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.hasMail(GitChangeSet.java:300)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.findOrCreateUser(GitChangeSet.java:284)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.getAuthor(GitChangeSet.java:339)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:311)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1400)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:175)
```

Some debugging steps I've tried:

- Email notifications are set-up and the email address is valid
- Under global config SMTP is set-up and the test email works
- Under Git plugin user.email is set to valid email
- The user being authenticated in the hook has a valid email address
- I've explicitly installed the Mailer plugin, the version is 1.6 (though I'm not sure why this might have been needed)

If I build manually the build fails but an email is sent to the notification address saying things are back to normal:

```
Started by user myuser
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@reop:project.git
Checking out Revision 745755b40716cc220f9635db7b555af65dd283b2 (origin/test)
Sending e-mails to: build@address.com
FATAL: hudson.tasks.Mailer$UserProperty.hasExplicitlyConfiguredAddress()Z
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.tasks.Mailer$UserProperty.hasExplicitlyConfiguredAddress()Z
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.hasMail(GitChangeSet.java:300)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.findOrCreateUser(GitChangeSet.java:284)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.getAuthor(GitChangeSet.java:339)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:311)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:307)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1400)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:175)
```

Subsequent builds will now work but I do not get the email (though this may be due to there being no changes?):

```
Started by user myuser
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@repo:project.git
Checking out Revision 745755b40716cc220f9635db7b555af65dd283b2 (origin/test)
Finished: SUCCESS
```

The next actual commit, triggering the job of course, we get the same error as the first one.

What's going on here? Have I missed a config option?

**Edit:** I wonder if it's something to do with the user initiating the commit hook? I'm authenticating the user by passing `https://user:pass@server.com/job_url` as the hook. It's authenticating (it wasn't before I added this as the anonymous user has zero privileges) but I still get some errors:

```
2013/12/16 22:54:49 [error] 18890#0: *576 readv() failed (104: Connection reset by 
peer) while reading upstream, client: IP_ADDRESS, server: myserver.com, 
request: "GET /job/job_name/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: 
"http://127.0.0.1:8088/job/job_name/", host: "myserver.com"
```

Weirdly with no config changes emails are now going out, but it's breaking right after the email sending, so the build is still marked as failed

```
Started by remote host 127.0.0.1
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
Fetching upstream changes from git@repo:project.git
Checking out Revision 3d93bdb4225635eb45526ca831781df2ed25a22b (origin/test)
Sending e-mails to: myemail@server.com
FATAL: hudson.tasks.Mailer$UserProperty.hasExplicitlyConfiguredAddress()Z
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: hudson.tasks.Mailer$UserProperty.hasExplicitlyConfiguredAddress()Z
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.hasMail(GitChangeSet.java:300)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.findOrCreateUser(GitChangeSet.java:284)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitChangeSet.getAuthor(GitChangeSet.java:339)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getCulprits(AbstractBuild.java:311)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:624)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1400)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:46)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:175)
```

Comment: I'm with the same problem. Looking at it, it seems it's a version conflict of jenkins with git plugin. The git plugin tries to access a method that was removed from jenkins. I'm still looking for a easy solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'fixed' this by uninstalling Jenkins:

`apt-get --purge remove jenkins`

I then added the current jenkins binary to `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/
```

After the usual `apt-get update` I then did `apt-get install jenkins` and got 1.5 something or other, the purge didn't remove the jenkins home directory so my jobs were still there though via the Jenkin UI I had to then upgrade some plugins.

I can now use the gitlab plugin as I have a much newer version of Jenkins, and the email issues went away.